# How to use Application.OnKey to stop the user from saving the file?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to stop the user from saving the file.

I have the code in the ThisWorkbook module and everything works except the first line `Application.OnKey "^{s}", ""`.

No errors are generated. It does not stop the user from saving the file.

I also tried `Private Sub Workbook_Activate()`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnKey "^{s}", ""
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Top = 25
    Application.Left = 25
    Application.Width = 640
    Application.Height = 735
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Make the file read only.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `Application.OnKey "^s", ""`